# How to create a mixed implementation of indeterminate checkbox?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am new in React, and I was wondering how you could create a mixed implementation of the indeterminate(tri-state) checkbox? All I could implement was till now was the vanilla 3 state checkbox, but I need to do this:

[image]

Could somebody direct me how to do this?

Edit:

I had used this code to start:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState(0)
    const indetSetter = React.useCallback(el => {
      if (el && state === 1) {
        el.indeterminate = true
      }
    }, [state])
    const onChange = () => setState(prev => (prev + 1) % 3)
    
    return(
        <Fragment>
            <input
                {...rest}
                ref={indetSetter}
                className={`checkbox__control ${className || ``}`}
                id={id}
                type="checkbox"
                value={value}
                checked={state === 2}
                name={name}
                onChange={onChange}
            />
            <span className="checkbox__icon" />
        </Fragment>
```

Comment: This site is recognized to solve problems or challenges, not to solve a task. give some of the code you have tried and ask for help, not ask to make the whole code for us

Comment: There are libraries for this. Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-three-state-checkbox or https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tri-state-checkbox or https://github.com/jchiam/react-three-state-checkbox (the first three results for Googling for 'react tri state checkbox').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to store an array of selected options in your state. On check or uncheck of one of the checkboxes, you could add or remove it from your state. The state of the group-checkbox can be derived by checking if none, some or all possible options are in state.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
const possibleOptions = ['option-0', 'option-1', 'option-2', 'option-3'];
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState([]);

// derive checked value for parent checkbox
const isParentChecked = selectedOptions.length > 0;
// derive indeterminate for parent checkbox
const isParentIndeterminate = isParentChecked && selectedOptions.length !== possibleOptions.length;

// add or remove child value to state on click
const onChildChecked = (e) => setSelectedOptions(prev => prev.includes(e.target.value) ?  prev.filter(it => it !== e.target.value) : [...prev, e.target.value]);

// select all or none when parent checkbox is clicked
const onParentChecked = (e) => !isParentChecked || isParentIndeterminate ? setSelectedOptions(possibleOptions) : setSelectedOptions([]);

// ToDo: Render UI and pass checked attributes and onChange callbacks
```